# How safe is Avast Bank Mode?

Tags: antimalware

If my computer is infected without me knowing it, how safe really is Avast Bank Mode (for Banking)?  Just curious as they sound pretty confidant when they say "Your banking transactions are safe."

Comment: You should really stop worrying about malware for banking. In most cases banks can reverse fraudulent transactions. On the other hand, the damage made by malware that steals/encrypts your personal data or spies on you (webcam, microphone, etc) can't be reversed. I would mainly about the latter.

Comment: The phrase they are using is nothing more than marketing fluff. It is not in their power to make it "safe". They can only make certain parts of the transaction safer. As Andre says, as long as you take reasonable precautions, banks - in most countries - will reimburse you (might not be true in some countries). Common sense is generally more important than anti-something tools.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned above, it's only a way of marketing their products. Every computer can be hacked one way or another. The best way to stay safe is by logging in using a live cd(kali linux or anything else).